# Java.io.FileNotFoundException : YAML file does not exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, yaml, filenotfoundexception

When I am submitting the spark job from terminal I am getting below error that file does not exists. Although I have already placed config file to my local.

**spark-submit command**:

> spark-submit --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku
> /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/target/scala-2.11/metorikku.jar
> -c /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml

**code**

```
    import com.yotpo.metorikku.configuration.job.{ConfigurationParser, Periodic}
    import com.yotpo.metorikku.metric.MetricSet
    import org.apache.log4j.LogManager

    object Metorikku extends App {
    val log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass)
    log.info("Starting Metorikku - Parsing configuration")
    val session = Job(ConfigurationParser.parse(args))

    session.config.periodic match {
      case Some(periodic) => {
      executePeriodicTask(periodic)
      }
      case _ => runMetrics(session)
      }

      private def executePeriodicTask(periodic: Periodic) = {
       val task = new Runnable {
       def run() = {
         session.sparkSession.catalog.clearCache()
         runMetrics(session)
        }
      }
       val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
       val initialDelay = 0
       ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay,    periodic.getTriggerDurationInSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      }

     def runMetrics(job: Job): Unit = {
       job.config.metrics match {
         case Some(metrics) => metrics.foreach(metricSetPath => {
           val metricSet = new MetricSet(metricSetPath)
           metricSet.run(job)
         })
          case None => log.warn("No mertics were defined, exiting")
       }
     }
   }
```

**error**

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException):
> File does not exist:
> /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml

Comment: could you run this `spark-submit --master local[*] --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/target/scala-2.11/metorikku.jar /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml`

Comment: why did you remove -c . I am passing argument to the program.

Comment: could you post the code snippet of reading the argument and using it in spark? so that let me replicate the issue?

Comment: added above. Please check

Comment: when i am running code from intellij its running fine but using spark-submit it is having issue file not found

Comment: Any solution please.

Comment: `-c` from where you are reading this external argument in your code?

Comment: can you check if the file actually exists there? you can try 'cat /home/hadoopuser/IdeaProjects/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml' and see if it prints output

Answer (score 0):

Metorikku looks for the files in HDFS, so you first have to copy the examples directory there:

```
hdfs dfs -put -f examples /user/hadoop/
```

Then you can run your job as follows:

```
spark-submit --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku metorikku.jar -c /user/hadoop/examples/movies.yaml
```